# Inspect each prediction in random forest

Tags: classification, predictive-models, random-forest

When we use elastic-net model for classification, we can check the coefficients and feature observations for each prediction, especially for those misclassified samples. For random forest, what are the methods to inspect each prediction? Besides looking at the variables that have top importance, is there any other way to get insights on which feature may be problematic in the model? It seems not quite convenient to print out some specific tree path to follow the prediction rules. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Aren't the coefficients in an elastic net model the same for all predictions?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean checking "coefficient times feature observation" for each account.

Comment: Coefficient times feature observation is the prediction, is it not?

Comment: I'll check the coefficient times feature observation for each feature separately and look into which feature takes most contribution towards the prediction.

Comment: That does not make sense to me. Could you please give an example?